# Why is Safari viewport can't be overflowed?

Tags: css, reactjs, safari

So I have this website about me, https://linar.netlify.app/, the footer page is accessible and can be clicked in chrome. However, in Safari, the user could scroll to the footer but somehow the screen is sprung back to the main making it not accessible and clicked. Does anybody know what is the problem?

Here is my index.css for this react project:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: ubuntu;
  src: url(../fonts/Ubuntu-Regular.ttf);
}

body {
  position: absolute;
  font-family: ubuntu;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  margin-bottom: 200px !important;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: auto !important;
  -webkit-background-size: auto;
  background-size: auto;
}

* {    
  margin: 0;
}
```

Here is the app.css:

```
Nav {
   position: fixed;
   top: 30%;
   right: 0;
   z-index: 1;
}

footer {
   -webkit-transform:translate3d(0,0,0);
   transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
   height: 200px;
   font-size: 12px;
   position: fixed;
   bottom: 0;
   left: 0;
   width: 100vw;
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
   justify-content: center;
   background-color: black;
   color: white;
   z-index: -3;
}

.footer-wrapper{
   display: table;
}

.footer-content{
   display: table-row;
   text-align: center;
}

.footer-icons{
   color: rgb(500, 500, 500, 0.5);
   height: 32px;
   width: 32px;
   margin: 8px;
   margin-bottom: 32px;
   margin-top: 32px;
}

.footer-icons:hover{
   color: white;
}

.main{
   background-color: white;
   position: relative;
   z-index: 0;
   height: 100vh;
   width: 100vw;
   -webkit-overflow-scrolling: auto !important;
}

.preloader{
   width: 100vw;
   height: 100vh;
   background-color: white;
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to set the body to **position: absolute;**
Remove that line and it will start working.

If you add the line **overflow-x: hidden;** to the body you will get rid of the ugly scrollbars that you will only see if you use a normal mouse (not the touchpad or the magic mouse)